# EJB with SOAP and XML

Tags: java, soap, ejb

I need to make application but I dont know where to start...

What do I need to do is to make stateless EJB that gets XML file trough SOAP, and parse that XML file.

I tried to make bean, but i relly dont know what to do first and how (I'm new in this area):

```
package ServiceX;

public class ServiceBean implements Service {

   public ServiceBean() {}
   public String GetXML(String xml) {
       return xml;
   }
}  

package ServiceX;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.Remote;

public interface Service extends Remote{
    public String GetXML(String xml) throws RemoteException;
}
```

Comment: SOAP usually means HTTP web service, not EJB.  Why would you want to do this?

Comment: Yes, I need to get XML file trough HTTP (XML is placed somewhere), then when I get it i need to read it (parse) and write its content into database...

Comment: Why don't you just write a SOAP service and leave EJB out of it?

Comment: sounds fine for me, but how? I'm really new in this area... tell me how to get xml with soap, and how to test it... thanks

Comment: btw I'm using JBoss...

Comment: JBoss hosts SOAP web services.

Comment: Learn how to do SOAP services with JBOSS and test them using SOAP UI.